# Can you record sound through vacuum? Like this: (object)(vacuum)(object)

Tags: acoustics, vacuum

There are these videos on youtube that play sound of Jupiter for example:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e3fqE01YYWs

Does anyone know if this is real at all? How can you record sound through vacuum space that separates Earth and Jupiter?

I'll generalize my question: is it possible to record sound through vacuum? Let's say you're on Earth with atmosphere and pressure, there is vacuum around it, and then there is a planet with atmosphere again. Is it possible to record sound on planet at all while being on Earth? Sound waves dont reach earth so is there an indirect method to doing that?

Comment: that's possible if u record sound with an instrument in jupiter's atmosphere and send it to earth via radio waves. But the sound is too scary to be true... i mean what's making that sound... the storm in jupiter ?

Answer (score 2):

Sound is carried by vibration of molecules (in air or a solid) so no you can't hear Jupiter from a distance in space.

The "sounds" in the video are the changes in electromagnetic field in Jupiter's atmosphere which vary at audio frequencies, measured by radio and then played as a sound.